# Javascript Array to mysql database using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how do I send a javascript array of x,y coordinates to a Mysql database? I don't have any forms or anything.

I'm very new the mysql so I basically know how to connect using this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
```

but I don't know how to connect that to the javascript. I know it has something to do with this code

```
jQuery.post(url, data);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you are searching for ajax

Comment: @kdlcruz This tutorial is outdated (feb 2013) and should not be followed. It uses `mysql`, which is [deprecated since PHP 5.5.0](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: @blex removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together this little one-page demo. Having a look at it might help you understand how it works.

To make it work, you need to put it on a server (*no way!*), and to have a table with `x` and `y` fields. Then, replace database credentials with your own.

**References**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**Live demo**

http://shrt.tf/coordinates

**Note**

This one does not check for types (you can input any String), but you can add that.

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Replace these parameters to match your database
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'mydatabase';
$table  = 'coordinatesTable';

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// If parameters are received
if(isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y'])){

    $error_messages = array();

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        $error_messages[] = "Couldn't connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    // Prepare insert
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` (x,y) VALUES (?,?)"))) {
        $error_messages[] = "Couldn't prepare statement: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    // Bind parameters x and y
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("dd", $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'])) {
        $error_messages[] = "Couldn't bind parameters: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    // Execute the insert
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $error_messages[] = "Couldn't execute the query: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    // Prepare some data to return to the client (browser)
    $result = array(
        'success' => count($error_messages) == 0,
        'messages' => $error_messages
    );

    $stmt->close();

    // Send it
    echo json_encode($result);
    // Exit (do not execute the code below this line)
    exit();

} // end if


// Fetch all the coordinates to display them in the page
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT x,y FROM `$table`");
$rows = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$mysqli->close();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
    <style>
    table{ border-collapse: collapse; }
    th,td{ border: 1px solid #888; padding: .3em 2em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>New coordinates</h1>
    <p>
        x: <input type="text" id="x"> 
        y: <input type="text" id="y">
        <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
    </p>
    <table id="coordinates">
        <tr>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>y</th>
        </tr>
<?php

if(count($rows)){
    foreach($rows as $row){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row['x']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['y']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}

?>
    </table>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#addBtn').click(postCoordinates);

            function postCoordinates(){
                var x = $('#x').val(),
                    y = $('#y').val();

                if(x.length && y.length){
                    // Change this if it is on a different page
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': url,
                        'method': 'post',
                        'data': {'x': x, 'y': y},
                        'dataType': 'json', // The server will return json
                        'success': function(res){
                            if(res.hasOwnProperty('success') && res.success){
                                $('#x, #y').val(''); // Empty the inputs
                                $('#coordinates').append('<tr><td>'+x+'</td><td>'+y+'</td></tr>');
                            } else if(res.hasOwnProperty('messages')) {
                                alert( res.messages.join('\n') );
                            }
                        },
                        'error': function(x, s, e){
                            alert( 'Error\n' + s + '\n' + e );
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('You need to provide x and y coordinates');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the array of cooardinates is to draw a line, so I'm trying to send something that looks kind of like this [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6].. I tried to change the data to just one value ''data': {'points': data},'  but I keep getting errors..  :(

Comment: this is the error message so far Error
parsererror
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

Search for ajax. Send the data from client side to server side:

For example:

```
  $('selector').on('click', function(){
      var coordinates = [x,y];

      $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'yourURL',
           data: {coordinates: coordinates},
           success: function(response){
               Console.log(response);
           }
        });
     });
```

In PHP:

```
    $coor = $_POST['coordinates'];
    echo $coor;

    //Search the manual of php for storing it in the database
```

**NOTE:**  Don't use mysql because it is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.